# Wordpress DB: options-table –> 32 gzipcompression?

Tags: database, options, compression

I just wondered what this row in the Wordpress Database refers to?

```
32  gzipcompression 0
```

I stumbled upon it in the WP options table. What if I set the value to `1`.

I do already have gzipcompression enabled via htaccess, so I simply wondered what this is?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's set in `schema.php`, [the WordPress Administration Scheme API](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L393). You can also find it in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference#Reading).

As you can see from a search through core, there's (as far as my search went) **exactly no use case** for it, aside from defining it as `0` when adding that option to the DB.

If you want to know if it's working on your site, just [enter your URL here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/).

Answer (score 1):

This option was used years ago to activate a handler for output buffering. It was off by default, and it didn’t work very good when enabled. Will be removed completely eventually.

See [Ticket #12996](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12996).